# While trying to see the content of a zipped file, I only get information about the zipping process

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, zip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gzip

In Ubuntu, installed on Windows Subsystem for Linux, I want to see the content of a zip file, using `gzip --list`.

I expected to see a list of included files like this:

```
FileName    ratio
File1       10%
File2       35%
...
```

Instead I just see some information on the compression of the zip file:

```
gzip --list "2019_02_04 05_01_24_Internal_File_2019_02_04 06_00_02.zip"
     compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
          38994                  -1   0.0% 2019_02_04 05_01_24_Internal_File_2019_02_04 06_00_02.zip
```

… and it's bogus information! 
How do I obtain a list of the files archived in that zip file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Gzip (`.gz`) and Zip (`.zip`) are two different file formats - you're using the gzip tool on a zip archive.

Try using `unzip -lv 2019_02_04 05_01_24_Internal_File_2019_02_04 06_00_02.zip`

The output should look something like this:

```
#unzip -lv test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     528  Defl:N      334  37% 2017-06-19 17:33 b9fd9cb9  test.py
--------          -------  ---                            -------
     528              334  37%                            1 file
```